# Is there anyway to create a centralized partial in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am pretty new to Rails. One of the requirement is to have a `Filter` Panel that would appear along each record list and will be used to filter records based on criteria. What actually I am looking for an HTML based UI of it that will contain input fields along with labels that I would like to pass from Controller. Since I will be using it across views so I don't want to put in a view specific folder. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually render partials from any folder. For example, in `users/show.html.erb` you can render a partial `_info` from, say, `transactions`.

```
 <%= render 'transactions/info' %>
```

A common thing to do is to put such shared partials into a separate directory with a descriptive name (I use "shared").

```
 <%= render 'shared/filter_panel' %>
```

Comment: Cool. I want to generate Filter Options by setting some parameters in Controller which should reflect in Partial. How could it be achieved? Should I create a helper function?

Comment: No, just set some parameters in the controller :)

Comment: Can you elaborate? Like, is it like passing params in render?

Comment: @Volatil3: yeah, you can pass params to render. Or you can set some instance variables in controller and access them from the partial

Answer (score 0):

you can put them in `/views/application/` dir, rails automatically look for partials in this directory

if you use the application directory then  you can just do `render 'partial'` from any view and it will render `/views/application/_partial.html.erb`

you can also create for e.g. `/views/admin/base` dir (if you have `admin/base_controller.rb`) and put your admin namespace partials there

if you have many partials, I recommend you put them into subdirectories